# How can I pass the correct path to my static files to my html in flask while using a route with another subdirectory?

Tags: python, html, flask, routes, jinja2

I created a route in flask and now suddenly all my static files aren't linked to my html anymore.

I linked my css like this in the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">
```

This is my route:

```
@app.route("/sid/<sid>")
def sid(sid):
    return render_template('sid.html')
```

When it renders it looks for the css in the following path:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/sid/static/css/main.css
```

I mean, I can understand that due to the fact I added /sid/ to the directory path, that the rendered html might look in the /sid/ directory for the static files, but the solution cannot be to create a folder /sid and duplicate all static files, can it?

How can I pass the correct path to the static files to my html?

Comment: start urls with `/` to get absolute url, not relative `href="/static/css/main.css"`

Comment: Thanks. I cannot believe it was that easy. If you want you can add it as answer below and I'll mark it as solution. I don't know how else I can show gratitude here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start url with `/` to get absolute url instead of relative one

```
 href="/static/css/main.css"
```